# Dell E6320 crashes with docking station

Tags: windows-7, crash, dell-latitude, docking-station

I have a Dell E6320 (i7 with 4GB mem, Win 7 Prof 32bit) that I use with three different Dell docking stations (model PR02X). The notebook frequently crashes when connected to a docking station. When unplugged from the docking station - no crashes. 
Sys config: Dell Wireless 5550 HSPA + mini card wireless modem, Dell Wireless 375 Bluetooth modem.

Comment: Please provide some more information. What kind of crash? BSOD? If so, what's the error message? Does it happen with all three docking stations? Have you tried other laptops in those docking stations? What OS are you running? What's connected to those docking stations?

Comment: @Indrek OS was posted in question

Answer (score 1):

You can install Bluescreen Viewer to identify the file at the source of any blue screens here:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

The associated files will be highlighted in red. Once we know which component is triggering the blue screens we can devise a course of action. This issue can be caused by any number of different software or driver packages. The most common causes seem to be Dell Control Point or NVIDIA display drivers. Updating or removing the software should correct the problem.